# glmnet with caret returns "Error in lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs, : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)"

Tags: r, r-caret, glmnet

(NB: I am aware that there are already several posts discussing this issue, but none of the solutions work for my dataset.)

I am exploring machine learning with caret for the first time using the inbuilt dataset "infert".

I want to make a random forest and a glmnet model and then compare the AUC scores of the two.

I start by renaming the output factor levels as it doesn't run if they are "0" and "1":

```
infert_y <- factor(infert$case) %>% plyr::revalue(c("0"="control", "1"="case"))
infert_x <- subset(infert, select=-case)

# Create cross-validation folds:
myFolds <- createFolds(infert_y, k = 10)

# Create reusable trainControl object: myControl
myControl_categorical <- trainControl(
  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
  classProbs = TRUE, 
  verboseIter = TRUE,
  savePredictions = TRUE,
  index = myFolds
)


# Fit a glmnet:
model_glmnet <- train(
  x = infert_x, 
  y = infert_y,
  metric = "ROC",
  method = "glmnet",
  preProcess=c("zv", "nzv","medianImpute", "center", "scale"),
  trControl = myControl_categorical
)
```

returns:

> Error in lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  :
> NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)

There are no missing or infinite values in the dataset and all of the x variables are numeric (no character variables).

I tried converting the x and y datasets to matrices as someone on another post said that helped:

```
x_matrix <- as.matrix(infert_x)
y_matrix <- as.matrix(infert_y)

# Fit a glmnet:
model_glmnet <- train(
  x = x_matrix, 
  y = y_matrix,
  metric = "ROC",
  method = "glmnet",
  preProcess=c("zv", "nzv","medianImpute", "center", "scale"),
  trControl = myControl_categorical
)
```

However I am still getting the same error. I have added all the preprocessing steps I can think of but none of them made a difference either.

Any ideas why this is happening (the random forest runs fine when given the same trainControl object)?

Comment: `infert_x` contains a categorical feature `education`, `glmnet` does not work with them. They must be converted to numeric. The must simple way is to use dummy encoding: new.x <- model.matrx(~., infert_x). And then use new.x as input to glmnet.

Comment: Ah I knew predictors couldn't be characters but I thought factors were okay! Will try that now, thanks!